# Identityserver4 Login ValidateAntiForgeryToken

Tags: c#, identityserver4

I have identityserver4 working, but I am facing an issue I don't know how to resolve. I downloaded a sample project from their GitHub repo (https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4.Templates). Using their IdentityServer4InMem sample, I am able to replicate exactly what I am experiencing.

If I run the project and open two tabs with the following url:
http://localhost:5000/Account/Login

If log in to tab 1, if I attempt to log in to tab 2 I get a HTTP ERROR 400.
I've researched it has to do with the ValidateAntiForgeryToken, if I take off the annotation, I do not get the error. Of course I can not do that in production, so I am trying to find a solution.

Comment: Just to update, I was able to use this example https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4/issues/2676 to overcome my issue.

Answer (score 1):

This issue has nothing to do with Identity Server.

To use [ValidateAntiForgeryToken] you need to @html.antiforgerytoken() in .cshtml file which creates a unique token in the hidden field but in .net core you don't need to use @html helper. This hidden field's token gets generated when you make HttpGet request for the login page and then it passes when you click on login button.

In your case when you are opening two tabs in browsers it creates token on a get request. And when you login from one tab (HttpPost request) your identity gets changed from anonymous user to some valid user in that case your previous token for an anonymos user is not valid anymore and it will always give you 400 status.

This feature prevents [cross-site request forgeries](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_request_forgery) where it avoids any form submission after the user is authenticated.

Comment: Mahesh More thank you for the great explanation of the problem, I still need a work around. This is related to Identity Server. I understand is not code problem with Identity Server.  In my case, a user has several app authorized to them, if they have let's say 4 tab open ( one app on each). I have an "idlerchecker" that logs them off when they're idle. Let's say they idle out and when they come back they're on the log on screen on all 4 tab, once they log in on one of the tabs, they'll get the error on all other 3. I am just looking for a work around. Thanks again for your explanation.

Comment: If you still think it's related to Identity Server try removing [ValidateAntiForgeryToken] attribute from your [HttpPost] method and everything will work as you expected.

Comment: yep, I did take off the annotation and it works, but I don't think that's the right way. I'll do a little more research to see if I can catch if the user is authenticated I'll try to find the app they're trying to log on to and then redirect them there.

Comment: Are you using .Net core or .Net standard? If you are using .Net standard you can catch HttpAntiForgeryException and if users is already authenticated you can redirect that user to login page. In login page verify that user is already authenticated and then redirect taht user back to returnUrl.

Comment: You can uppdate your Login [HttpGet] like below.
[HttpGet] public async Task<IActionResult> Login(string returnUrl) 
{ // If user is already authenticated then don't need to sign-in again, so we can redirect user to the return URL. if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated) { return Redirect(returnUrl);
 } // To Do }

Comment: I am using .Net Core, keep in mind the [HttpGet] happens when they're logged off. So at the time that all the apps were logged off, all the gets would be anon. Once they do the Post (log in) if one tab is authenticated, makes the other forgery token not good, I believe that's the spot I need to catch and redirect. I already have some code which catches the 400 error, I just need to implement the getting the correct redirect uri. Thanks again.

Comment: Ohh in .Net core you can't find HttpAntiForgeryException. And yes I know HttpGet will happen when user logoff but once user click on login button it throws an exception which you need to capture it and redirects to HttpGet and in HttpGet you can redirect it to returnUrl by checking User is authenticated, see above comment for HttpGet code. If you implement differently I would like to see your code.